# BGA Adaptor Wanted

Tags: bga, breadboard, breakout

I'm looking for a low cost adaptor/breakout board for a 64 ball BGA chip (0.8mm pitch) [PDF of chip datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads1298)

I want to use the chip with a bread board, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

BGA chips are very unfriendly for prototyping with directly. Generally if a chip comes in BGA form, you should purchase a pre-made development board with the chip already attached. Even if you made your own PCB, they are very difficult to solder correctly with hobby level tools (Yes there are youtube videos of guys doing it with a candle and a hairdryer or something, but that's not the norm). The only BGA protoboard adapters I've heard of are from [SchmartBoard](http://www.schmartboard.com/index.asp?page=products_bga&id=110) -- but a quick look at their site only shows 1.27mm and 1.00mm pitch BGA adaptors, 0.8mm is too small for them. A random google search found these [ZIF Sockets](http://www.emulation.com/catalog/off-the-shelf_solutions/prototyping_adapters/bga/)...but I suspect they may be out of their price range. Yes, that's right, pick your jaw up off the floor, that price is for a single piece.

---

EDIT: I just looked up the part number, ADS1298 from TI, and it comes in TQFP. Get that instead!! It will be much cheaper, easier, and save you a ton of headache instead of trying to prototype with the BGA part. When you're ready to sell a million of your gadgets, then you can hire a factory to solder on the BGA's for you, but until then, stick to the TQFP.

Comment: it's just not currently available in QFP as the chip is only available as a prototype BGA right now.....thanks for all the help tho!

Comment: It actually shouldn't be too hard to solder that BGA with a hot air soldering gun, i'd probably also pre heat the PCB.  If your near a university with a decent EE department they may let you use their lab for a few minutes.

Comment: I was hoping to do it in that fashion cuz i've got a heat gun, just need to find a suitable PCB - not sure if it would be cheaper to get one made up?

Comment: your going to have a hard time doing it with a heat gun.  You need control over the air flow and temperature and theres a decent chance you'll kill the chip in the process.  What you really want to do is look up the reflow temperature profile for the IC and use a IR temperature gauge to follow it as closely as possible.

Comment: did find these guys: http://www.emulation.com/catalog/off-the-shelf_solutions/prototyping_adapters/bga_csp/bga_csp.cfm

But for $115 each i'd probably just design the PCB for the entire circuit and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but a little bit of googling found me this: http://www.adapters.com/Packages/bga_package.htm

Comment: cheers - unfortunately it's the wrong layout, it's the right pitch tho so it's a start!

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to a sort-of related question: [Pre-programming surface mount ICs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/pre-programming-surface-mount-ics/2784#2784)

Comment: ok - I don't see anything about BGAs? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: There are links to places that sell adaptor boards. Perhaps one of the sites sells the adaptor you need.

Comment: Actually, as I looked through those sites just now, I didn't see any BGA adapters. Sorry about that.

Comment: Could you get the part in its TQFP-64 package instead?

Comment: sorry it's currently only available as a proto BGA

Comment: @ Pingswept - Cheers for havin' a look tho