# What's the purpose of this checkerboard pattern?

Tags: pcb, manufacturing, architecture

This gigabit Ethernet NIC has a checkerboard pattern out of copper etched on the PCB:

[image: Imgur]

Each square is electrically isolated. What's the point of adding these? I guess that the PCB isn't filled with a copper plane due to cost concerns, but why don't leave it empty then?

Comment: Related answer on theiving: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/17211/15622

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's called copper thieving.  It helps balance the amount of copper on the outer layers which makes the etching process easier.  Basically it helps them avoid over or under etching the board.

Usually I'll have a note on my board files that I send to the fab house like: Fab may add copper thieving at their discretion so long as it is at least 100 mil from any major feature.  Which basically means theive all you want but don't get it near any of my signals.

Why not just fill the outer layers with copper pour then?  It's not cost, etching a pcb is not an additive process.  They start with a full sheet of copper and burn it away. Having copper pour all over the place close to my signals!!! That would cause impedance discontinuities everywhere.

Plus depending on how it's routed you don't want to unbalance your board, for example having plenty of copper pour on the bottom but little on the top.  That will lead you into having your board cup and curl when it goes through the oven.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer! As per cost, I know how boards are etched. I heard that the removed copper (or used etching solution) can and will be recycled, especially for large-scale runs.

Comment: Great point, I guess they can extract that copper out so it might affect cost as well.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Copper is not just eteched away, at least in some processes.  The ones I am familiar with start with a thin copper layer, which is built up with plating where traces are supposed to remain, then the remaining thin areas are etched away.  It would be wasteful, expensive, and most importantly inaccurate to etch away thick copper.  Imagine a board with 2 or 4 ounce finished copper thickness.

Comment: True I didn't mention plating, I was just trying to point out that you don't start with a piece of bare (as in no copper anywhere) FR4 and then somehow add copper to that.

Comment: I should also say thanks for the comment btw.  I never really thought too hard about it and I thought plating happened after etching.  When you look at it though that would obviously be a nightmare.  What kind of crazy bus bar solution would you need to get current everywhere!  Resist first then plating, then etching makes much more sense.  So thanks for making me go learn something :)

Comment: From what I understand, board houses used to discard used etchant (which contained lots of ionic copper) but that nowadays the value of the copper in used etchant is below the cost to reclaim it.  The more copper is left on a board, the less will be available to reclaim.

Answer (score 0):

##### THIEVING:

> The addition of dummy copper pads to the open spaces on the outer layers of a PCB in order to provide a uniform
> distribution of copper across the entire surface. The purpose is to
> insure plating currents are uniform across the whole surface when
> plating copper onto the PCB surface and in the holes. This helps
> insure a uniform plating thickness across the surface and in the
> holes.
>
> – Ritchey, L. (2003), *Right the First Time Vol.1* [p.252]

[image: Thieving on High-Speed Board]

##### Further Details:

> [...] A common problem with the pattern plating process is the lack of
> uniform distribution of copper surfaces to be plated across the entire
> panel surface because component density varies across the surface. As
> a result, where there are few features to be plated, the plating
> current will be dense and the thickness of the plated copper will be
> much greater than in areas where there are many features, such as a
> BGA pattern or a high pin count connector. The primary problem with
> this is variations in finished hole size--a big issue when press fit
> connectors are part of the assembly. To solve this problem, a pattern
> of dummy pads can be added in areas where there are few features. This
> is called thieving because it robs plating current from the other
> features in the area. The objective is to make sure the plating
> current is even across the panel so that copper is plated to a uniform
> thickness. Figure 4.23 is an example of a PCB with thieving added to
> the outer layers. An important thing to remember when thieving is
> added to the outer layers of a PCB is if there are controlled
> impedance traces in the next layer down, layer 2 or n-1, thieving must
> not be placed over those traces or thieving must be accounted for in
> the trace design notes (i.e., noting where thieving is possible and
> where it is not).
>
> – Ritchey, L. (2006), *Right the First Time Vol.2* [p.56]