# Custom Boards With Custom Programmed Microcontroller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, manufacturing

I have built a prototype for a project that I'm trying to manufacture. The prototype uses an arduino, but I'm unsure how to get that produced on a larger scale. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. I'm really just in search of a way to get my the code that I loaded onto my arduino built into an AVR microcontroller, and how to implement that into my design. If it helps, I'm only using nine pins, and my arduino is an uno. Also, where is a good place to get boards manufactured that include sockets for microcontrollers. I havent' decided how many to manufacture yet, not until I work out this and a few more kinks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us how many units you plan to manufacture. Are we talking about a few hundred or hundreds of millions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pre-programming surface mount ICs](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/pre-programming-surface-mount-ics)

Comment: I don't think this question covers any ground that hasn't already been covered by previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, microcontrollers are programmed at manufacture. You supply the binary files to the assembly company and they'll flash the chips.

Some chip vendors will ship you chips pre-programmed with your image for a fee. This is likely only cost effective once you are ordering 1000s of units.

See also:
[Pre-programming surface mount ICs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/pre-programming-surface-mount-ics)

Comment: What manufactures do this? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: No, picking the right manufacturer will depend on your location, budget, project complexity, lead times, etc.

Comment: Do you know of any specific ones that do allow this. I'm very new to this

Comment: Custom manufacturing is a huge topic. Here's a gentle introduction - http://www.make-digital.com/make/vol26/?pg=34&pm=2&u1=friend#pg34

Comment: What manufacturer do you use?

Comment: I work for a company who uses Chinese contract manufacturing, orders are 10K minimum. We use a local PCB and assembly house for prototypes, who do a reasonable job but cost a fortune. Questions and answers on electronics.stackexchange.com aim to be useful to all and not "too localized", so this isn't the right place to get quotes and contact details.